# How to bind text literal surrounded by wildcards using MySqli prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I know how to do it in PDO way:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bricks ";
$sql .= "WHERE text LIKE :phrase AND tags LIKE :tag ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY hearts DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$pagesOnSite}";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(':phrase', '%'.$phrase.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':tag', '%'.$tag.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

How do the same query in stmt way. I tried something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bricks ";
$sql .= "WHERE text LIKE ? AND tags LIKE ? ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY hearts DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$pagesOnSite}";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", "%".$phrase."%", "%;".$tag.";%");
$stmt->execute();
```

But it returns:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference
```

Comment: You need to assign the string value to a variable, then pass that variable into `bind_param`

Comment: @JonStirling You mean that i should change $phrase and $tag to "%".$phrase."%" and "%;".$tag.";%" before using bind_param?

Comment: @Steve143 yes. The joys (sarcasm) of passing by reference with these mysqli functions :(

Comment: @IncredibleHat But what if user put "%"? How bind_param will see the difference in string?

Comment: @JonStirling can you change my code, i don't understand exacly how should it look like :/

Comment: @Steve143 if a user puts % in the input, it would behave exactly as you have it the other way. You are concat'ing them onto the string. If you do not want users to input %... then strip them out before using them in any sql query (same goes for PDO).

Comment: @IncredibleHat but in PDO i can make a difference to SQL server. I mean that user can put it if he wants to but their "%" will be only string in my query and my "%" will be proparely used

Comment: This: `'%'.$phrase.'%'` is no different than this: `$var = '%'.$phrase.'%'`. In either PDO or mysqli. In PDO doing `$query->bindValue(':phrase', '%'.$phrase.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);` is susceptible to the same issue because you have not escaped any of the `%` inside `$phrase`. If you want to allow a user input of `%` to be just `%` and not a wildcard... then escape it before concat'ing any wildcards to it for the query.

Comment: @IncredibleHat how to escape this? by mysqli_real_escape_string?